# android center align custom view as ViewPager title

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using a viewPager and I need the pager titles to hold a custom view.
The custom View is a simple view with two custom textViews in it as I need specific fonts and colors for each textView in the title. It looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/bg_med_dark_gray">

    <com.example.customviews.TextViewPlus
        android:id="@+id/assetNameTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:text="SOMETEXT"
        app:customFont="CONDUIT_LIGHT"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="19sp"/>

    <com.example.customviews.TextViewPlus
        android:id="@+id/assetValueTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:text="OTHERTEXT"
        app:customFont="CONDUIT_LIGHT"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="19sp"/>.

</LinearLayout>
```

I want the **title pane to view 3 titles** at a time when the first view is centered and nothing on the right.

When scrolled or clicked to the next item it will have the following:
first Item on the left, current item in the center and next item (or none if last) on the right.

Using the android PagerTitleStrip i can set everything this way only that the title has a fixed color and can't accept a view.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If PagerTitleStrip does the work for you, why not extending it? :)

Here's the code from [grep](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.java)

Add a method which accepts font and color customization, or better a custom TextView and there you go! Blessed will be the god of open source

Comment: It's not possible to copy this class as it has several private methods in Parent classes.